# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my Java code?

Tags: java, arrays

Why am I getting this error?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at Vectores.main(Vectores.java:86)

I think the mistake is here:

```
System.out.println("El Número mayor es:"+NMay);
System.out.println("El Número menor es:"+NMen);
if (NumP>0){
    System.out.println("Hay"+" "+NumP+" "+"Números Pares");}
else { System.out.println("No hay números Pares"); }
if (NumI>0){
    System.out.println("Hay"+" "+NumI+" "+"Números Impares");}
else { System.out.println("No hay números Impares"); }

for (i=0;i<N-1;i++){
    for (j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        if(Num[i]>Num[j]){
            aux=Num[i];
            Num[i]=Num[j];
            Num[j]=aux;
        }
    }
}

System.out.print("El Vector ordenado es: ");
for (ord=0;ord<N;ord++){
    System.out.print(Num[ord]+", ");
}

for(Imp=1;Imp<=N;Imp=Imp+2){
    SumI=SumI+Num[Imp];
}

System.out.print("La Suma de las Posiciones Impares es:"+SumI);
```

I've made the file available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/837fmkto8v2kiez/Vectores.java).

Comment: What's `N` and which line is 86?

Comment: -1 for not identifying line 86.

Comment: FYI, I perceive it as presumptuous and rude to post a block of code on this forum ... and then ask other people to debug it for you.  You're not paying anybody here consulting fees.  Tell us what you've done to try and debug this and why you haven't been able to solve the problem.  Java IDE's all have robust debugging features; you ought to be able to step through code just as well as anybody else can.

Comment: You use `...<N-1` one place, `...<N` another, and `...<=N` in a third place. One of those likely isn't what you want - you're asking for index 3 when the array isn't that long, probably because one of those comparisons. Also, what the others said :).

Comment: It is your "Imp" loop, you can add a breakpoint there and check it out..

Comment: Now that we see line 86, it's clear that you probably don't realize that arrays are 0-based in Java. This makes for(Imp=1;Imp<=N;Imp=Imp+2) walk potentially one beyond the end of your array Num.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Imp=1;Imp<=N;Imp=Imp+2){
    SumI=SumI+Num[Imp];
}
```

When your Imp = N, you try to access Num[N] which is illegal, as your array contains indexes from 0 to (N-1). The stop-argument in the for loop must **not** be Imp<=N, as it allows the program to try to access Num[N].